# undefined reference to `lzma_code'

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries

I try to pack my application and static link all libraries. But I get this error.The Makefile is shown below:

```
CC          = gcc
INCPATH     = -I/home/johnny/Application/FileBasedReG/include/RealityGrid
LIBS        = -L/home/johnny/Application/FileBasedReG/lib/RealityGrid -lReG_Steer -l:libxml2.a -l:libncurses.a -l:libm.a -l:libz.a -l:libtermcap.a

OBJECTS     = mini_steerer.o

TARGET      = mini_steerer

###### Compile ######
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(INCPATH) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

mini_steerer.o: ./mini_steerer.c ./mini_steerer.h
    $(CC) -c $(INCPATH) -o mini_steerer.o ./mini_steerer.c
```

I think I need to add one or two more static libraries, but I can't find what they are.

Answer (score 6):

On a debian / ubuntu system, `apt-get install liblzma-dev` will do the trick.  Link with -llzma.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the `liblzma.a`, which should have come as a dependency from `libxml2`, if you had got it from a package.